# Cleaning CSV file before reading

Tags: go

I'm reading a big CSV file with `encoding/csv` library.

But this file is a bit non-standard and contains non-escaped quotes `"` breaking the reader at `parser.Read()`:

> 2022/06/09 17:33:54 parse error on line 2, column 5: extraneous or missing " in quoted-field

And if I use `parser.LazyQuotes = true`, I'm getting:

> 2022/06/09 17:34:15 record on line 2: wrong number of fields

Faulty CSV file (reduced to its minimum) `foo.csv`:

```
1|2
"a|b
```

So I need to remove all occurences of double quotes `"` and I'm currently doing it on the whole file from terminal using `sed 's/"//g'`, but I want to remove it from Go script instead.

How should I do it knowing that I'm reading the file like this:

```
func processCSV(filepath string){
    file, err := os.Open("foo.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    parser := csv.NewReader(file)
    parser.Comma = '|'
    // parser.LazyQuotes = true

    _, err = parser.Read() // skip headers

    for {
        record, err := parser.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // process record

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an [io.Reader](https://godoc.org/io#Reader) that removes quotes from data read through an underlying io.Reader.

```
// rmquote reads r with " removed.
type rmquote struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (c rmquote) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := c.r.Read(p)

    // i is output position for loop below
    i := 0

    // for each byte read from the file
    for _, b := range p[:n] {

        // skip quotes
        if b == '"' {
            continue
        }

        // copy byte to output position and advance position
        p[i] = b
        i++
    }

    // output position is the new length
    return i, err
}
```

Plumb it in between the CSV reader and file:

```
parser := csv.NewReader(rmquote{file})
```